# Links created in HighCharts are preventing their default bindings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm trying to create links that open a bootstrap modal out of the xAxis categories in a highchart chart.  I've been able to make the links, but I can't seem to prevent highcharts from breaking the default binding nor am I able to add new bindings.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue.

```
$(document).on('click','.dont_follow_do_log',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLtakdhz/

Comment: please do not use [bootstrap] as tag. that's another thing

Comment: You can use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin, which allows to add click event on label.

Answer (score 2):

The links aren't actual `<a href="` tags, they're `onclick` events.

You can do something like

```
$('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels tspan').attr('onclick','');
```

But then you'll lose the links all together. If you really need the links there, you might try getting the `.attr('onclick')` and wrapping the tspan in an `<a>` instead. Could be styling issues with that approach though.